# ViewChild element undefined when referenced before view initialized

Tags: angular, typescript

what I'm trying to achieve is the below

use a string to access ViewChild then add class to it

but it gives this error " Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined"

```
@ViewChild('projects', { static: false }) projects: ElementRef;

someFunc(){

  let data = 'projects'
  let elementToMarkActive = this[data]

  elementToMarkActive.nativeElement.classList

}
```

Comment: You're referencing the element weird -- why not just `this.projects`? This also depends on timing (if you call `someFunc` from `ngOnInit`, you need to set "static" to true on the ViewChild decorator arguments), or, it's possible the element doesn't exist for some other reason. Do you have an element marked with `#projects`? Is there an `*ngIf` on the element that could cause it to not exist when you call `someFunc`?

Comment: Would be easier to diagnose if you show the template.

Comment: yeah weird, data here comes as string from subscription to observable, 
the code in question is a demo, 
set "static" to true solved it, thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements selected using `ViewChild` decorators are not available in `ngOnInit` (or any other lifecycle phase prior to view rendering and initial change detection) without the `static` argument set to true.

Please reference [the documentation for ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) for more information.